# How can I create a JFrame composed of a JLayeredPane with the ability to draw over an Applet?

Tags: java, applet, draw, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to create a GUI in which I can draw "above" an Applet based on the content within the Applet.  To test this I'm trying to fill in a simple rectangle by creating a panel with a filled background to appear over the applet, through use of a JLayeredPane.  I cannot get this to work however I try it.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI {

private static JFrame frame;
private static JLayeredPane layers;
private static JPanel panel;
private static Applet applet;
private static final String JAR_PATH = "file:C:/Applet.jar";

public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
    ClassLoader clientClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL(JAR_PATH)});
    Class<?> client = clientClassLoader.loadClass("Loader");
    frame = new JFrame("JLayeredPane Testing");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    applet = (Applet) client.newInstance();
    layers = new JLayeredPane();
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(200, 200);
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    layers.add(panel, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
    layers.add(applet, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER);
    frame.setContentPane(layers);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    applet.init();
}

}
```

The applet doesn't show or initialize when I run my program.

Comment: The question is a bit schizophrenic: are you dealing with a JFrame or an Applet? Please clarify. You also appear to be trying to mix AWT and Swing components -- why? What's the motivation behind this strange set up?

Comment: I'm dealing with an Applet but I'm hosting it within a JFrame.

Comment: Why? And why are you trying to load an AWT heavy weight component into a JLayeredPane?

Comment: I'm not very good with GUI or Swing components, should I be using a light weight component instead? If so, what should I use?

Comment: You usually don't display applets in JFrames to begin with. I'm still not sure why you're doing what you're trying to do. What is the motivation behind all of this?

Comment: I'm trying to do this to create a transparent screen over the actual game, as a pause screen.

Comment: So the applet is not of your creation but rather is a third party program?

Comment: Yes it is a third party game, and I'm trying to draw "on" it by hosting the applet within a self created frame.

Comment: Do you know that this can even be done? It sounds a bit sketchy to me, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to say that I know it to be impossible.

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible I've seen it done before with other games

Comment: Try drawing the applets contents to a BufferedImage, then draw the image to your jframe. Also forward events to the applet. I don't think you should be mixing AWT and swing.

Comment: If you are not very good in Swing better look at example http://www.codemiles.com/java/jframe-on-applet-t385.html

Comment: Did you try thinking reverse. Deal with JFrame and host it in applet.

Comment: I haven't thought about Applet hosted in a JFrame, I'll try that now.

Comment: Hosting the Applet in a JFrame didn't work.  If anyone out there is still trying to attempt this or is going to; this is basically all I'm looking for: Host an applet within a JFrame, be able to draw "over" the applet while still being able to interact with the applet.

Comment: *"an Applet"*  What applet?  Be specific, provide an URL.  This may be much simpler or harder, depending on the details of how the applet was written.  It might also make more sense to extend the applet than add it to another container.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should try drawing the contents of the applet to a bufferedimage.
`BufferedImage buf=new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`
Override paint in your jframe

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
   applet.paint(buf.getGraphics());
   g.drawImage(buf, 0, 0, this);
   super.paint(g);
}
```

Then you can add Swing components on top. Also figure out what events you need to forward to the applet. Use `applet.get____Listeners()` (eg getMouseListeners, getKeyListeners, etc.) to get the event listeners of the applet. Then forward events to the listeners.

Comment: Actually, I realize it isn't _entirely_ safe to call paint directly, but you can try it...

Comment: Another comment (sorry for clogging this up) but you could try painting the applet directly with the graphics "g" instead of using the BufferedImage

Comment: ..and yet, chat happens.  I would not get too worried about it. Comments 'compact' after 5 and if anyone is deeply caring about it, they can flag the comment for deletion.